# Il verbo metterci può essere utilizzato di forma "impersonale"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, grammar, word-choice, pronouns

Ho un dubbio sull'uso del verbo pronominale *metterci*. Può essere utilizzato di forma "impersonale", o dobbiamo sempre coniugare *metterci* per un soggetto preciso?
Gli esempi che seguono sono sbagliati?

"Quanto ci mette a postare il video?"

"Andare da Venezia a Vicenza ci mette un'ora in treno."

"Quanto ci mette a portarci le pizze?"

O, invece, per dire questi frasi sarebbe meglio usare l'altro verbo pronominale, *volerci*, che ha un uso più impersonale?

Ho letto sul tema in tanti siti diversi, ma non sono riuscita a trovare spiegazioni su questo uso specifico.
Per chi vuole leggere un po' su questi verbi pronominali: https://www.italianochefatica.it/it/metterci-e-volerci/.

Grazie mille!

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE! Nell'uso impersonale dovrebbe essere "quanto ci si mette".

Comment: Nelle tre frasi di esempio stai sottintendendo un soggetto noto a chi parla? Per esempio la prima sottintende, poniamo, Piero? Cioè: “Quanto ci mette Piero a postare il video?” Così andrebbe bene; altrimenti, se il senso è “quanto ci vuole...”, con “ci mette” non si capisce.

Answer (score 4):

La prima e la terza delle espressioni che hai indicato hanno un significato diverso da quello che, credo, tu voglia dire:

"Quanto ci mette a postare il video?"

È una domanda che ci si fa quando qualcuno deve postare un video ed è in ritardo.
Il senso di questa frase è:

"Come mai ci mette così tanto a postare il video?"

"Quanto ci mette a portarci le pizze?"

Come per la frase precedente, questa frase indica che qualcuno è in ritardo (colui che deve portare le pizze) e ci si domanda da cosa possa dipendere il ritardo.

Nell'altro esempio, invece, c'è un chiaro errore di verbo.
"Andare da Venezia a Vicenza ci mette un'ora in treno."

Per indicare il tempo del viaggio si può dire:
"Andare da Venezia a Vicenza **richiede** un'ora in treno."

oppure

"**Per** andare da Venezia a Vicenza **ci vuole/serve** un'ora in treno."

Inoltre solitamente si usa dire "un'ora **di** treno" (dove si sottointendono le parole "viaggio in":

"un'ora di *viaggio in* treno").

Answer (score 3):

Effettivamente, come si spiega nel libro *Nuovo Contatto C1. Corso di lingua e civiltà italiana per stranieri* (Loescher Editore, Torino) di R. Bozzone Costa, M. Piantoni, E. Scaramelli e C. Ghezzi, la particella pronominale *ci* si trova

> come particella fissa in alcune **espressioni idiomatiche** quali 
>       *volerci/metterci* = occorrere: *Da qui a casa mia ci vogliono dieci minuti a piedi*.
>
> [...]

Se vuoi usare *metterci* coniugato in modo impersonale, trovi una combinazione di due clitici.

Come spiega questo l'[articolo "clitici" dell'Enciclopedia dell'Italiano Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/clitici_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/),

> *La formazione dei cumuli è basata su uno schema di priorità, che dispone i clitici nell’ordine indicato dalla [tab. 2](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/clitici_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/#gallery-in-text-4) (Cordin & Calabrese 1988: 589)*.

Puoi vedere nella tabella sopra indicata che la particella *ci* va prima del *si* impersonale.

Quindi, nell'uso impersonale, le tue frasi dovrebbero essere

- Quanto ci si mette a postare il video?
- Per andare da Venezia a Vicenza ci si mette un'ora in treno.
- Quanto ci si mette a fare una pizza?

Personalmente, da un punto di vista semantico (non grammaticale), l'uso impersonale con "portarci le pizze" mi pare piuttosto strano: mi sembra che si stia dicendo che tutte le persone impiegano la stessa quantità di tempo per portarci le pizze. Ma forse avrebbe senso nel contesto di una pizzeria dove si va sempre con lo stesso gruppo e dove di solito ci vuole la stessa quantità di tempo per preparare una pizza, non so.