# Meaning of "ci" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, particles

"Casa di Gloria è molto lontana dalla stazione, quindi **ci** mette tanto tempo per arrivare."

What would be the meaning of "ci" in the sentence above? I understand that it sometimes means "qui" but this meaning does not seem to fit in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Related question: https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13510.

Answer (score 6):

In that sentence, *metter*ci** (*io **ci** metto*, *tu **ci** metti*, *egli/ella **ci** mette*, etc...) is a "verbo pronominale"; that "***ci***" modifies the meaning of the verb *mettere*, just like "up" in "to give up" modifies the meaning of the verb "to give".

Here "*metter**ci***" means "to need": *Gloria's house is far from the station, therefore she needs a lot of time to arrive [there]*

It might be worth mentioning that "*mettere*" + "*ci*" can also be used to express its literal meaning of "to put here/there"; it is the context of the sentence to suggest which meaning is the correct one:

- *se viaggi in auto, **ci metti** due ore ad arrivare* -> If you travel by car, **you need** two hours to arrive / **it takes** two hours to arrive
- *mi piace questa borsa, posso **metterci** dentro tutto quello che mi serve* -> I love this bag, I can **put in it** everything I need

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about this ambiguity.